# CKEditor post value with ajax post old value

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor

I'm trying to post CKEditor textarea value with AJAX.
I'm using this code founded in this community:

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

The value is posting not correctly. AJAX posts the *old* value.
Example:
If textarea1 value is 'hello', AJAX posts nothing. By clicking again the submit button, it sends 'hello'. Now if I update the value, with 'ciao', it sends 'hello' again, but if I resend the value, it posts 'ciao'.
I'm not sure if anyone has understood what I'm saying.
What's the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['DOM-ID-HERE'].getData();
```

or

```
var value   = CKEDITOR.instances.'DOM-ID-HERE'.getData();
```